# How to manage IIS from C#?

Tags: c#, .net, iis-7

I would like to write a service that does some IIS management tasks for me, like creating virtual directories or adding new applications.

Is it possible to do some management of IIS by a C# application or WCF service.

Comment: [What have you tried](http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/165/how-to-use-microsoftwebadministration/)?

Comment: How would I go about? Is there a DLL present I could use? The idea is doing some research before building it. That why I asked it. Never done something like this before. I don't even know if it is possible.

Comment: See the link I provided. :-) I found it searching for _"C# manage IIS"_, I guess it'll do what you want.

Comment: @CodeCaster, I didn't see that your comment was a link ;-)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It looks like you can use the [Microsoft.Web.Administration api](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.web.administration%28VS.90%29.aspx) to do most tasks with IIS 7+.  Would that meet your requirements?